# How to install SASM correctly on arm64 Ubuntu m1 silicon? I don’t have a macro.o file…

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, gcc, arm64

I installed SASM on Linux (Ubuntu with arm64) on my M1 Mac. When I try to Build my NASM code, I get the following error:

```
gcc: error: /tmp/SASM/macro.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’
```

I tried `sudo apt install gcc-multilib` but I got the following error:

```
Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: What architecture are you trying to build for? AFAIK `-m32` refers to 32-bit x86, I doubt it's a valid option for arm

Comment: we are learning x86 assembly on a 32 bit architecture, but the linux architecture, I honestly dont know what I need, please if you have a clue what could help, tell me!

Comment: It *may* be possible with a cross-compiler toolchain - I don't know for sure. If it was easy, someone would have answered this [How to run X86 NASM on Macbook Air with M1 Chip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235026/how-to-run-x86-nasm-on-macbook-air-with-m1-chip)